# How to input chinese character in bash console?

Tags: bash, lxterminal

My system is lubuntu,all chinese character can be displayed correctly,and it can be input correctly on gedit , leaf ,firefox.
It can't be inputed on my bash console,how to fix it?

```
locale
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Here is my /etc/bash.bashrc file.

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
shopt -s checkwinsize
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Here is my  /root/.bashrc file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%:/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
```

Here is my normal bashrc config file.

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%:/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

And i can copy chinese character into clipboard and paste it into terminal console,the chinese character can be displayed from my paste.
My terminal is lxterminal.
The input method is fcitx.
The chinese character can be inputted in XTerm .
Now to login in with root username,here is my desktop.
[image]

To press ctrl+alt+F1,to input root and its passwd,login into pure text interface,and input command `startx`, another desktop appear.
[image]

The chinese character can be inputted in its lxterminal.
questions:
Why there are two desktop photo for the same user `root`?
Why chinese character can be inputted in the next lxterminal?
Now to press ctrl+alt+F7,come back to the previous desktop,
[image]
chinese character can not be inputted in its lxterminal.

Comment: How is your terminal configured?

Comment: choroba did ask how your _terminal_ is configured.  Not your shell.

Comment: What "console" are you referring to? Do you mean the `tty`s accessible through Ctrl+Alt+F1 etc? Or is this about terminal emulators like `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`?

Answer (score 2):

There's a terminal emulator program built into the Linux kernel.  It is built over the frame buffer and input event devices, internally, and presents itself to application-mode systems as a series of *kernel virtual terminal* devices, `/dev/tty1` and so forth.  Strictly speaking this is not *necessarily* your *console*, which could be a serial terminal device.  But let's skip over that, because answering for that would involve knowing what terminal hardware was at the other end of the serial link.

The terminal emulator program that is built into the Linux kernel does not support input methods.

So to have a non-X11 terminal with input methods you need to run a *user-space virtual terminal* that uses the frame buffer and input event devices.  They disconnect the in-kernel terminal emulator from those devices, whilst they themselves are using them.

User-space virtual terminal emulators that support input methods include

- [zhcon](http://zhcon.sourceforge.net/) ([Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zhcon))
- [fbterm](https://code.google.com/p/fbterm/) ([Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/fbterm)) and its forks such as [jfbterm](http://jfbterm.sourceforge.jp/) ([Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/jfbterm))

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177209/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132

Answer (score 0):

[image]
To login with normal name.

[image]
To login with root.

To delete the three lines in /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc  and /root/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
```

vim /etc/X11/Xsession.d/25xchinput

```
export LAGN=zh_CN.utf8
export LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.utf8
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
fcitx &
```